# Getting value of second occurrence using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using the below code in my XSL:

`<xsl:if test="S_DTM/C_C507/D_2005=123">
     <EstimatedArrivelDateV2><xsl:value-of select="S_DTM/C_C507/D_2380"/></EstimatedArrivelDateV2>

    </xsl:if>`

However, there are two nodes of D_2005 that will be true for "=123". Each of these has a different value in the child element (D_2380).

What I'm struggling with is returning the value of the second instance of D_2380. I've tried the '[2]' notation but it breaks the XSL. I need to keep as XSL v1 if possible.

thanks

Input is below - I'm looking to return the value '201907141253'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hub:HubMessage
    xmlns:hub="http://www.example.org/HubMessage"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/HubMessage HubMessage.xsd">
    <hub:HubMessageRequest>
        <hub:MessageType>D42Edifact</hub:MessageType>
        <MessageRequestData>
            <D42Edifact>
                <S_UNB>
                    <C_S001>
                        <D_0001>UNOA</D_0001>
                        <D_0002>1</D_0002>
                    </C_S001>
                    <C_S002>
                        <D_0004>ABC</D_0004>
                        <D_0007>XXX</D_0007>
                    </C_S002>
                    <C_S003>
                        <D_0010>MOL</D_0010>
                        <D_0007>001</D_0007>
                    </C_S003>
                    <C_S004>
                        <D_0017>190604</D_0017>
                        <D_0019>1108</D_0019>
                    </C_S004>
                    <D_0020>7599</D_0020>
                </S_UNB>
                <M_IFTSTA>
                    <S_UNH>
                        <D_0062>7272</D_0062>
                        <C_S009>
                            <D_0065>IFTSTA</D_0065>
                            <D_0052>D</D_0052>
                            <D_0054>96B</D_0054>
                            <D_0051>UN</D_0051>
                        </C_S009>
                    </S_UNH>
                    <S_BGM>
                        <C_C002>
                            <D_1001>23</D_1001>
                            <D_1131/>
                            <D_3055/>
                            <D_1000>IFTSTA</D_1000>
                        </C_C002>
                    </S_BGM>
                    <S_DTM>
                        <C_C507>
                            <D_2005>137</D_2005>
                            <D_2380>201906071253</D_2380>
                            <D_2379>203</D_2379>
                        </C_C507>
                    </S_DTM>
                    <G_SG4>
                        <S_CNI>
                            <D_1490>1</D_1490>
                        </S_CNI>
                        <G_SG5>
                            <S_STS>
                                <C_C601>
                                    <D_9015>1</D_9015>
                                    <D_1131/>
                                    <D_3055>6</D_3055>
                                </C_C601>
                                <C_C555>
                                    <D_9011>ETAUPDT</D_9011>
                                </C_C555>
                            </S_STS>
                            <S_RFF>
                                <C_C506>
                                    <D_1153>VT</D_1153>
                                    <D_1154>ABCFA2AX1K1Z51338</D_1154>
                                    <D_1156>J0744</D_1156>
                                </C_C506>
                            </S_RFF>
                            <S_RFF>
                                <C_C506>
                                    <D_1153>VT</D_1153>
                                    <D_1154>ABCHA2A16K1F70673</D_1154>
                                    <D_1156>J0744</D_1156>
                                </C_C506>
                            </S_RFF>
                            <S_RFF>
                                <C_C506>
                                    <D_1153>BL</D_1153>
                                    <D_1154>18000650655</D_1154>
                                </C_C506>
                            </S_RFF>
                            <S_RFF>
                                <C_C506>
                                    <D_1153>BN</D_1153>
                                    <D_1154>18000650655</D_1154>
                                </C_C506>
                            </S_RFF>
                            <S_DTM>
                                <C_C507>
                                    <D_2005>123</D_2005>
                                    <D_2380>201906131253</D_2380>
                                    <D_2379>203</D_2379>
                                </C_C507>
                            </S_DTM>
                            <S_NAD>
                                <D_3035>CA</D_3035>
                                <C_C082>
                                    <D_3039>MVT</D_3039>
                                </C_C082>
                            </S_NAD>
                            <S_NAD>
                                <D_3035>CZ</D_3035>
                                <C_C082>
                                    <D_3039>XYZ</D_3039>
                                </C_C082>
                            </S_NAD>
                            <S_LOC>
                                <D_3227>ZZ</D_3227>
                                <C_C517>
                                    <D_3225>CNXNA</D_3225>
                                </C_C517>
                            </S_LOC>
                            <G_SG6>
                                <S_TDT>
                                    <D_8051>S1</D_8051>
                                    <D_8028>0166A</D_8028>
                                    <C_C220>
                                        <D_8067>1</D_8067>
                                        <D_8066>9207388</D_8066>
                                    </C_C220>
                                </S_TDT>
                                <S_LOC>
                                    <D_3227>ZZ</D_3227>
                                    <C_C517>
                                        <D_3225>CNXNA</D_3225>
                                    </C_C517>
                                </S_LOC>
                                <S_LOC>
                                    <D_3227>PL</D_3227>
                                    <C_C517>
                                        <D_3225>SIKOP</D_3225>
                                    </C_C517>
                                </S_LOC>
                                <S_LOC>
                                    <D_3227>PD</D_3227>
                                    <C_C517>
                                        <D_3225>CNXNA</D_3225>
                                    </C_C517>
                                </S_LOC>
                                <S_DTM>
                                    <C_C507>
                                        <D_2005>186</D_2005>
                                        <D_2380>201906042010</D_2380>
                                        <D_2379>203</D_2379>
                                    </C_C507>
                                </S_DTM>
                                <S_DTM>
                                    <C_C507>
                                        <D_2005>123</D_2005>
                                        <D_2380>201907141253</D_2380>
                                        <D_2379>203</D_2379>
                                    </C_C507>
                                </S_DTM>
                            </G_SG6>
                        </G_SG5>
                    </G_SG4>
                    <S_UNT>
                        <D_0074>19</D_0074>
                        <D_0062>7272</D_0062>
                    </S_UNT>
                </M_IFTSTA>
                <S_UNZ>
                    <D_0036>1</D_0036>
                    <D_0020>7599</D_0020>
                </S_UNZ>
            </D42Edifact>
        </MessageRequestData>
    </hub:HubMessageRequest>
</hub:HubMessage>
```

and the current XSL is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" exclude-result-prefixes="xs fn">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
      </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="D42Edifact">
    <D42Edifact>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_UNB"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="M_IFTSTA"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_UNZ"/> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_UNT"/> 
    </D42Edifact>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S_UNB">
    <InterchangeHeader>
        <Syntax_identifier>
            <Syntax_ID><xsl:value-of select="C_S001/D_0001"/></Syntax_ID>
            <Syntax_version><xsl:value-of select="C_S001/D_0002"/></Syntax_version>
        </Syntax_identifier>
            <Sender><xsl:value-of select="C_S003/D_0010"/></Sender>
            <Recipient><xsl:value-of select="C_S002/D_0004"/></Recipient>
       </InterchangeHeader>          
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="M_IFTSTA">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG4"  /> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G_SG4">
    <SG4>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG5"  /> 
    </SG4>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G_SG5">
    <SG5>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_STS"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_RFF"  />
        <EventDateTime><xsl:value-of select="S_DTM/C_C507/D_2380"/></EventDateTime>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_LOC"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG6"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="G_SG7"  />

    <xsl:if test="S_DTM/C_C507/D_2005=123">
     <EstimatedArrivelDateV2><xsl:value-of select="S_DTM/C_C507/D_2380"/></EstimatedArrivelDateV2>        
    </xsl:if>




    </SG5>  
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="G_SG6">
    <SG6>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_TDT"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_LOC"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_DTM"/>
    </SG6>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="G_SG7">
    <SG7>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="S_EQD"/>
    </SG7>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="S_UNT">
    <MessageTrailer>
                <Segments>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D_0074"/>
                </Segments>
                <MessageID>
                    <xsl:value-of select="D_0062"/>
                </MessageID>
            </MessageTrailer>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S_UNZ">
    <InterchangeTrailer>
        <ControlCount>
            <xsl:value-of select="D_0036"/>
        </ControlCount>
        <InterchangeID>
            <xsl:value-of select="D_0020"/>
        </InterchangeID>
    </InterchangeTrailer>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S_RFF">

    <xsl:if test="C_C506/D_1153='VT'">
    <VehicleRecord>
        <VIN><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1154"/></VIN>
        <DistCICode><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1156"/></DistCICode>
    </VehicleRecord>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C506/D_1153='BL'">
        <BillOfLoading><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1154"/></BillOfLoading>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C506/D_1153='BN'">
        <BookingNumber><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1154"/></BookingNumber>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C506/D_1153='EQ'">
        <ContainerNumber><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1154"/></ContainerNumber>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C506/D_1153='SR'">
        <SRNumber><xsl:value-of select="C_C506/D_1154"/></SRNumber>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="S_STS">
    <StatusInfo>
            <Status><xsl:value-of select="C_C555/D_9011"/></Status>
    </StatusInfo>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S_TDT">
        <Transport>
            <StageQual>
                <xsl:if test="D_8051='L1'">
                    <xsl:text>DomesticLeg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="D_8051='S1'">
                    <xsl:text>ShippingLeg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="D_8051='F1'">
                    <xsl:text>InternationalLeg</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>  
            </StageQual>
            <Conveyance_ref_number><xsl:value-of select="D_8028"/></Conveyance_ref_number>
            <Mode_of_transport>
                <xsl:if test="C_C220/D_8067=1">
                 <xsl:text>Ocean</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                 <xsl:if test="C_C220/D_8067=2">
                 <xsl:text>Land</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </Mode_of_transport>
            <VesselDetails>
            <xsl:if test="C_C220/D_8067=1">
                    <VesselCode><xsl:value-of select="C_C220/D_8066"/></VesselCode>
                    <VesselName></VesselName>
                    <VesselFlag></VesselFlag>
            </xsl:if>
            </VesselDetails>
        </Transport>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="S_LOC">
    <xsl:if test="D_3227='ZZ'">
        <EventLocation><xsl:value-of select="C_C517/D_3225"/></EventLocation>               
    </xsl:if>
       <xsl:if test="D_3227='PR'">
        <PlaceOfDelivery><xsl:value-of select="C_C517/D_3225"/></PlaceOfDelivery>               
    </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="D_3227='PL'">
        <PlaceOfLoading><xsl:value-of select="C_C517/D_3225"/></PlaceOfLoading>               
    </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="D_3227='PD'">
        <PlaceOfDischarge><xsl:value-of select="C_C517/D_3225"/></PlaceOfDischarge>               
    </xsl:if>
           <xsl:if test="D_3227='PR'">
        <PlaceOfReceipt><xsl:value-of select="C_C517/D_3225"/></PlaceOfReceipt>               
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="S_DTM"> 
    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=35">
        <ActualDeliveryDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></ActualDeliveryDate>               
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=123">
        <EstimatedArrivelDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></EstimatedArrivelDate>               
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=178">
        <ActualArrivalDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></ActualArrivalDate>               
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=186">
        <ActualDepartureDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></ActualDepartureDate>               
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=196">
        <EarliestDepartureDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></EarliestDepartureDate>               
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=231">
        <EarliestArrivalDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></EarliestArrivalDate>               
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="C_C507/D_2005=334">
        <StatusChangeDate><xsl:value-of select="C_C507/D_2380"/></StatusChangeDate>               
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="S_EQD"> 
    <EquipmentDetails>
            <Type>
                <xsl:if test="D_8053='CN'">
                    <xsl:text>Container</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="D_8053='TP'">
                    <xsl:text>Transporter</xsl:text>
                </xsl:if>
            </Type>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="C_C237/D_8260"/></ID>
    </EquipmentDetails>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: *"I've tried the '[2]' notation but it breaks the XSL."* Show us your attempt, so we can fix it. And we need to see the input too - see: [mcve].

Comment: The value I'm trying to return of '201907141253' should be going in <EstimatedArrivelDateV2>

Comment: I have rolled back your question to what it was when I answered it. If you have a different question, post it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I see only one `G_SG5/S_DTM/C_C507` element that has a `D_2005` child with the value of `123`. Its `D_2380` value can be retrieved using:

```
<xsl:template match="G_SG5">
    <SG5>
        <!-- ... -->
        <EstimatedArrivelDateV2>
            <xsl:value-of select="S_DTM/C_C507[D_2005=123]/D_2380"/>
        </EstimatedArrivelDateV2>    
    </SG5>  
</xsl:template>
```

The result will be:

```
<SG5>
   <EstimatedArrivelDateV2>201906131253</EstimatedArrivelDateV2>
</SG5>
```

Demo: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9N

Comment: Apologies - I've corrected the original post. You're right - there is only one child value but it still doesn't return the correct value

Comment: It returns the expected value - see: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFN1y9N